# Apache 2.4 Forward proxy TLS connection refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-2.4, vault

I am trying to run hashicorp vault server in a Docker container behind an Apache Forward Proxy (httpd v2.4; running in a container for testing purposes).  Vault is set to use AWS KMS for Autounseal.  However, vault gives the following error. No log information is being generated by the proxy.

```
vault_1  | Error parsing Seal configuration: error fetching AWS KMS wrapping key information: RequestError: send request failed
vault_1  | caused by: Post "https://kms.<region>.amazonaws.com/": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 172.28.0.2:9081: connect: connection refused
vault_1  | 2022-03-20T16:32:13.188Z [INFO]  proxy environment: http_proxy=http://proxy:9081 https_proxy=http://proxy:9081 no_proxy=".127.0.0.1,localhost,testproxy"
```

The Apache Proxy is configured as follow

```
Listen 9081
<VirtualHost *:9081>
  ServerName 0.0.0.0

  ProxyRequests On
  ProxyVia On
  SSLProxyEngine On
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyTimeout 300 

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all 
    Allow from all 
  </Proxy>

  AllowCONNECT "9081" 

</VirutalHost>
```

I have tried turning on and off various Apache modules.  I've tried setting `HTTPS_PROXY` to `https://proxy:9081`.  All this to no avail.  What settings do I need to allow this proxy connection to go through?

Comment: Could you perhaps add a network diagram to your question? It's clear that KMS can't be contacted, the question is why. You could add a KMS endpoint to your VPC, but they cost a little bit of money.

Comment: In this test case I'm not using a VPC.  So a VPC endpoint won't work here